# How to limit random binary generation with a for-loop? (More details in question, including code)

Tags: c#, for-loop, random, binary

I am trying to make a simple C# console application that generates random binary code. The binary generation works fine, but I'm trying to limit it using a for-loop. However, this doesn't work. The application generates infinite binary code, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help! From my knowledge, the for-loop should only generate 5 random binary digits. Code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class BinaryGen
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            i = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int b = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    Console.Write(b);
    b = rnd.Next(0, 2);
}
```

You change the state of the counter i to 1 or 0, so the loop is infinite.